# Set size to fill a space

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-interface

```
foreach (TableContainer table in listOpenUnjoinedTables)
            {
                var item = new Label();

                item.MouseEnter += item_MouseEnter;
                item.MouseLeave += item_MouseLeave;

                if (table.IsVirtual == false)
                {
                    item.Content = "[" + table.TableDescription + "]";
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Content = "[" + table.View.Name + "]";
                }

                item.Tag = table;
                cmb.Items.Add(item);

                if (item.ActualWidth > largestWidth)
                {
                    largestWidth = item.ActualWidth;
                }
            }

            if (largestWidth != 0)
            {
                foreach (Label label in cmb.Items)
                {
                    label.Width = largestWidth;
                }
            }
        }
```

I've got a ComboBox and am adding labels to it, instead of ComboBoxItems. I would like that the labels fill the whole space in the dropdown list. I'm trying to code above, however the label's width is always returning as 0, so my code does not work.

How can I accomplish this? I would like for the ComboBox's items (labels) to fill the whole drop down list's width.

Comment: Why are you creating UI elements in code to begin with? That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore - It's created dynamically at run time. This is just a quick sample app

Comment: Wrong. If you need Dynamic UI, use `DataTemplates`, and probably an `ItemsControl`. Don't create UI elements in code. this is not win(hack)forms. Even if it is a quick application, do it right.

Comment: Also, you're adding items to the ComboBox based on that `listOpenUnjoinedTables`. Why don't you bind the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property to that and use a proper `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: That still doesn't solve my problem @HighCore. I am aware that this is not the way to go about it, but I have my reasons. The problem I am asking about would still be present even if I created the UI elements in XAML.

Comment: Use `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties. Your code is still wrong.

Comment: What would the alignment properties accomplish?  Can they allow me to make the label fit into the whole drop down list width?

Comment: Dude, I can't understand what you're doing. Your code is a mess. Create the proper XAML and post the XAML and a screenshot of what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that in a real world application it wouldn't make any sense at all to have Label controls as ComboBox items.

Anyway, the minimal Style shown below, assigned to the ComboBox's [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) property, will take care for proper horizontal stretching of the items.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```